# To Clear input field value from a button and to get back the same value on the field from another button

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement to clear an input field value using a button and get the same value with the click of another button.

Basically, I have one Input field and two buttons(click1 and click2).

When I click the click1 button, the value is getting cleared but when I click the click2 button, it is showing true instead of the value, could anyone please guide me?

```
<input  ng-model="c.filterName"  >

<button ng-click = "c.click()">Click 1</button>

<button ng-click = "c.clicks()">Click 2</button>



c.click = function(){
        c.filterName = '';
    }
    
    
    c.clicks = function(){
        c.filterName = !'';
    }
```

I have tried the above code, and it is working but I want the exact value on the input field that got cleared and not the boolean value(currently I am getting as true and not the value).

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the value of `c.filterName` to original value, I will suggest you store the original value in the `$scope` when you call the `c.click()` function and then set the `c.filterName` to null:

```
c.click = function() {
  $scope.originalFilterName = c.filterName;
  c.filterName = '';
}
c.clicks = function() {
  c.filterName = $scope.originalFilterName;
}
```